# How to get headphones and speakers working at the same time?

Tags: speakers, headphones

I have a Gigabyte P55-UD3 motherboard which comes with a Realtek sound card and audio header for the front panel. My headset is permanently connected to the front panel (mic in, headphones in) and I also have speakers connected at the rear of the computer. What I want to achieve is that both the headphones and the speakers work at the same time.

On my old PC with Realtek, I was able to do this by clicking "Device advanced settings" in the Realtek HD Audio Manager and then clicking "Make front and rear output devices playback two different audio streams simultaneously" and then doing some reassigning of front/rear settings in the Realtek Audio Manager (can't remember the details).

But that doesn't seem to be working now - either the speakers play sounds or the headphones, not both at the same time.

To pose the question differently, Windows plays the sounds on the "default device". I'd like to make both headphones and the speakers kind of like the default devices.

Comment: Are they audio jacks or are they USB?

Comment: Where do I find the Realtek HD Audio Manager?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You need to disable "Front panel jack detection". This will make the front and rear jacks play the same stream.

Source: http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/243915-49-realtek-audio-manager-sound-signal-simultaneously-front-rear

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Holy crap this has been bugging the crap out of me today. Thanks!

Comment: How can I get the Realtek Audio Manager? I downloaded the latest driver from Realtek website but it didn't come with it.

Comment: With the latest drivers, you strangely also need to go into "Device Advanced Settings" and enable the option "Mute the internal output device, when an external headphone plugged in." Otherwise, it treats the two output jacks as different audio devices.

Comment: This doesn't work in the latest drivers since the "front panel jack detection" option doesn't exist. The similar-looking "Disable auto popup dialog when device has been plugged in" option doesn't work either. But this answer was useful in hinting me to find an old version of the driver which had that option. The latest Realtek driver that had the option was 2.62 (for example, 2.67 lacked that option). Installing that, disabling jack detection and using the "Mute the internal output device, when an external headphone plugged in" option fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Worked on AsRock B365 Pro4 with Realtek HD Audio. Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

I solved the problem with **different output to the front panel**
on my ASUS P5P43TD.

All you need to do is to go to *Onboard Devices Configuration* in BIOS
settings and **change Front Panel Type** from **HD Audio** to **AC97**

After restarting you have now Tab called **HD Audio 2nd output**
in *Realtek Audio Manager* (but keep Speakers tab as default output).

If you can't see that Tab, go to *Device Advanced Settings* and change it to
**Make Front and Rear output devices playback two different audio streams simultaneously.**
If you choose the other option in Advanced, you will have only one stream
but from both outputs - front and rear.

And now you have multiple choice for output in popular applications
such as audoi- and video-players, where you can change output to
**Speakers** or to **HD Audio 2nd output**.

As a result my Foobar2000 (audio) and MPC (video) are playing
onto different outputs as I'm typing this post.

For some games you can choose the output too (Black Ops) in game
Sound options but in some of them you cannot (MW II)
BTW if you don't set anything as Default in Realtek Audio Manager
you won't have any sound in MW II and some other games.

Answer (score 11):

You could always buy a headphone splitter for a few *$$ or ££ or €€*

[image: headphone splitter]

Comment: This was my solution for a long time too, especially when I couldn't do it on some cards at all. But this often stresses the jack more and much more often I had to mess with it a bit to have stereo everywhere, etc. - especially when it wasn't splitter with cable like in your picture, but a single piece. I'm glad I can use software toggle in that Realtek Audio Manager. This should be standard option when computer has multiple output jacks.

Answer (score 5):

Got this working finally. If you are able to get the above screen with both "Speakers" and the "HD Audio 2nd output" tabs. (ie front panel headphone jack) then do as described above - click the yellow folder in Realtek HD audio Manager and check disable front panel jack detection). For whatever reason, this changes the "HD Audio 2nd output" to "Mic in at front panel (pink)" which was not visible before.  Set speakers as default and click "Device advanced settings" and mute the rear output device when headphones are plugged in. Not sure why you would have to select this, but this was the only way to get mine working.

Couldn't there just be a check boxes for all devices and what sounds to play through them? Seems this would be easy to implement.

ADDED: Tested the previous answer - selecting speakers for the front panel device type does work without having to disable front panel jack detection but you still have to keep "Mute the rear audio device when headphones are plugged in" checked. It basically combines the front panel and rear jacks into a single output and you lose independent control of front panel audio.

Comment: This works, I had to check "Mute the rear output device, when a front headphone plugged in". This is messed up, it looks like they swapped the flag incorrectly.

Answer (score 3):

You want the SAME sound out of the front "headphone" (green jack) and speakers, both together, And NOT to mute speakers when you plug in the headphones?

In that case in the Audio Manager (should open when you plug headphones in), click the front green jack icon, and tell it you plugged in front speakers, NOT headphones - now you should have the same sound from your main speakers AND your headphones.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your hardware. Your old machine sounds like it had a card that was capable of multiple output streams. Check out the specs on your Gigabyte board and see if the sound card is capable of this.

Also, do you have the same 'Realtek HD Audio Manager' as you did on your old PC? If you do, check to see if this option is there. If it is not, it's probably hardware incompatibility.

Comment: The new Audio Manager looks practically the same as the old one and the option is still there - it just doesn't work the same any more. But maybe I'm missing some important configuration setting?

Answer (score 1):

I had a heck of a time getting both to output simultaneously.  The previous answers may not work for setups like mine since I'm using **analog** headphones and **digital** USB speakers.  Here's a quick rundown of my settings (pretty sure these are what count).

Realtek HD Audio Manager:

- Disable front panel jack detection
- Make front and rear output devices playback two different audio streams simultaneously

Playback Devices:

- Headphones set as Default Device and Default Communications Device

Recording Devices:

- Realtek Digital Input checked Listen to this device, playback through Headphones
- Stereo Mix set as Default Device and Default Communications Device, checked Listen to this device, playback through Speakers

Once I got it working it still worked *immediately after* disabling Realtek Digital Input, but I swear I could not get it to work **before** it was enabled.

**Update:** While the above configuration might work for you I highly recommend using [Voicemeeter](https://www.vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/) for such a problem.  You'll likely have more consistent results.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the simplest way is to buy a little USB sound card for around 7 €.