# Can I have the internal subwoofer remain playing while using the audio out jack on an ASUS N45SF notebook?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, drivers, audio

I have an ASUS N45SF notebook. It comes with a dedicated subwoofer in addition to the built-in speakers.

When I connect any audio device to the audio out jack, the internal speakers remain silent, and the subwoofer too.

What I want is to keep the subwoofer active/playing even with an audio device connected to the audio out jack.

Are there any drivers or settings in the OS which could enable this behaviour? I have Win7/Ubuntu dualboot so OS doesnt matter.

Comment: related: http://superuser.com/questions/120602/how-to-get-headphones-and-speakers-working-at-the-same-time