# How to use both front and rear audio simultaneously? (MSI A320M)

Tags: audio, port, windows-installer

After researching multiple sources it seems MSI A320M VD/S m-atx motherboard should be able to be used with 2 mic inputs and 3 audio outputs at the same time - 2 front ports, 3 rear ports.

However I could only get front or back to work, not both at the same time.

[msi realtek audio consol screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0Zbe.png)

Answer (score 0):

After trying different options, this solution solved it! [How to get headphones and speakers working at the same time?](https://superuser.com/questions/120602/how-to-get-headphones-and-speakers-working-at-the-same-time)

- in Realtek audio console,
- click on the settings option near the ports
- check the option "Disable the front panel popup dialog"

Now both front and back audio ports play the same sounds at the same time.

[disable front panel popup dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuZgY.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have previously used an application called Voicemeter which can be used for audio routing, I used it to output audio to my TV via HDMI and to a USB headset at the same time.