# How to get headphones and speakers working at the same time on windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, speakers

I have the same situation in [here](https://superuser.com/questions/120602/how-to-get-headphones-and-speakers-working-at-the-same-time), but I have windows 10. My realtek driver hasn't got the option "front panel detection", and it seems that there are no old enough versions of Realtek drivers that are suitable for windows 10... What can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

This is more a workaround than a solution, but in case no solution is presented, this workaround could save you a lot of trouble.

You can buy a stereo splitter audio cable:
[image]

Make sure that it is stereo male to 2x stereo female (important, because you also have stereo male to 2x mono female). Connect the male to your computer, and the speakers in one port, your headphones in the other.